# Node.js redirecting traffic from domain to specific port

Tags: node.js, minecraft

so I don't know if this is even possible, but one of my close friends gave me this node.js script that is supposed to do the following:

When someone connects to a Minecraft server with a.FreeMinecraftHost.com:25565 (That's the default port of minecraft, when you have your server running with the default port, clients don't have to type in a port) it is supposed to redirect them to say a.FreeMinecraftHost.com:30000

Here is the code he gave me:

```
var Socket = require('net').Socket;
var Server = require('net').Server;
var net = require('net');

var SERVERMAP = {
  'a.FreeMinecraftHost.com:25565': ['localhost', 30000],
  'b.FreeMinecraftHost.com:25565': ['localhost', 30001],
  'c.FreeMinecraftHost.com:25565': ['localhost', 30002],
  'd.FreeMinecraftHost.com:25565': ['localhost', 30003]
};
var server = new Server();
server.on('connection', function(client) {
  var buffer = '';
  var authed = false;

  client.on('data', function(data) {
    if(!authed) buffer += data;

    if(!authed) {
      var parser = new RegExp('([a-z0-9_]+);([^:]+):([0-9]+)', 'ig');
      var parts = parser.exec(buffer.toString().replace(/\0/ig, ''));

      if(parts) {
        var serverString = parts[2] + ':' + parts[3];
        authed=true;

        if(SERVERMAP[serverString]) {
          var socket = new Socket();

          socket.connect(SERVERMAP[serverString][1], SERVERMAP[serverString][0],     function() {
        socket.write(buffer);

        socket.pipe(client);
        client.pipe(socket);
      });
    } else {
      client.end();
    }
  } else {
    client.end();
  }
}
  });
});
```

The problem is that when I run it, it does nothing, node doesn't keep it alive or anything, I'm just instantly returned to the prompt

**EDIT**
I got it working! Kind of, I forgot,

```
server.listen(25565);
```

at the end, so now I can connect to the Minecraft server and it works, but when the Minecraft Client Pings it in your server list, it shows as offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to have load balancing i would suggest to do one of two things

a) nginx and proxy pass

```
upstream minecraft_servers {
  server 127.0.0.1:30000;
  server 127.0.0.1:30001;
  server 127.0.0.1:30002;
  server 127.0.0.1:30003;
}

server {
  listen 25565;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://minecraft_servers;
  }
}
```

b) haproxy loadbalancing
more info here http://haproxy.1wt.eu/